Не получается импортировать большую базу данных SQL в Open Server через консоль. Выдает ошибки
testDB - пустая бд. Путь к файлу правильный. Пробовал через SOURCE, также не выходит. cd написал
$ mysql -u root testDB < B:\ospanel\domains\bd\rybak96.com.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@DBC_links






/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT *' at line 1```



Если через SOURCE выдает это

```ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@DBC_links' at line 1 mysql> SOURCE B:\ospanel\domains\bd\users10.sql ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@DBC_links INSERT INTO b_user (ID, TIMESTAMP_X, LOGIN, PASSWORD, `CHEC' at line 1 ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'testdb.b_user' doesn't exist ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@DBC_links' at line 1```



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Команде mysql -u root не надо передавать параметры, это вход под пользователем.
Для импорта БД используйте следующую инструкцию

Заходим под пользователем:
mysql -u root


Подключаемся к базе данных:
use testDB 


Импортируем БД:
source путь до бд



